# Adjusting the Extent of Sub basins file with the Correct one

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, r

I am working in ArcGIS. I am also the learner of R. I need a solution for correcting the Extent of sub basin sahpefile with a complete basin. I have a correct complete file of basin Called LCC. its extent are
Top: 3582990.96241773       Bottom: 3382896.9805397
Left: 219786.440776942      Right: 400720.171941948[image: Study area file]

the extent of the sub basin file that made by spatial Join of 7 basin is
Top: 7.513928 dd          Bottom: 5.895039 dd
Left: 98.152079 dd        Right: 99.620746 dd

I want to correct the sub basin file.

One more thing is important that few weeks ago in ArcGIS I did correction but I merges the internal boundaries of the basins. I need a solution that I can separate all the sub basins command areas correctly, for the further analysis at each sub basin in my research.

Comment: What stops you of repeating few weeks old correction?

Comment: When I performed the set data source from the properties It merges the internal boundaries because the correct file has just external boundary of the whole command area. LCC external Boundary. But i need a file that has extent of LCC correct file along with all sub basin boundaries that I can split them again and perform the spatial analysis of water resources management components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution in ArcGIS, So I want to share with it for the new learner like me. But Still I am looking for the solution R.
Just go to the 
Spatial adjustment, then 
start editor,
again in Spatial adjustment tool and go to 
Set Adjust data, 
select All file, 
then go to 
Adjust Methods, 
Transform Projective, 
then Select 
New displacement link Tool, 
Select the respective 3 or 4 points from the file you want correct the extent to the correct extent file
then go to spatial adjustment tool and click
Adjust

File be corrected. Stop editing and enjoy the work